# Passing json object to db as 'payload' -rails postgrel

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, dom

I have been working on something using the gojs library, which is a library that ables you to generate diagrams, from tournament brackets to family trees etc..

I'm using a save function to submit my set of data to my model via **formData**,

```
function save() {
      var tojs = myDiagram.model.toJSON();
      var json = JSON.stringify(tojs);

      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("payload", json);

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("post", "http://localhost:3000/malesingle", true);
  request.send(formData);
                }
```

My controller as a set of action following the parsing of payload into params.
def create

```
   @tournoi = Tournoi.new(payload: JSON.parse(params[:payload]))
      if @tournoi.save
        redirect_to  malesingle_url
```

I even used serialize to avoid any trouble while passing the object into tthe model :

```
class Tournoi < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :payload, JSON
end
```

my model is set-up in a way to accept a json object into the data as **'payload'**, thanks to postgrel on rails.

```
class CreateTournois < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :tournois do |t|
      t.json 'payload'
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

After saviing the tournoi, the following action is suppose to be a redirection to another view if `@tournoi.save redirect_to malesingle_url`
The json object is passed throu the parameters as **payload** it is inserted into tournois table then committed into the data-base.
i get a **TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String): app/controllers/tournois_controller.rb:7:in create**
after clicking on save button, my browser show me an action controller exception with a ** no implicit conversion of nil into string ** highlighting `@tournoi = Tournoi.new(payload: JSON.parse(params[:payload]))`

while inspecting my page i console on my javascript console a warning **Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead.**
i went online to look a bit around to understand why im getting this message they all mention dom modification, which what i'm tryiing to do by assigning a json object to data, what i dont uderstand is on my terminal it shows that my object is saved but i get an error. just doesnt really make any sense to me .

Comment: Did either of these work? `request.send(JSON.stringify(tojs))` or if it doesn't map automatically `request.send({payload: JSON.stringify(tojs)})`

Comment: @Nope i get a TypeError on  `request.send(JSON.stringify(tojs))` and a syntaxerror on `request.send({payload: JSON.stringify(tojs)})` and nothing inserted into my db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error is always raised when using `@tournoi = Tournoi.new(payload: JSON.parse(params[:payload]))`, The TypeError is raised specifically on **JSON.parse(params[:payload])**.
So by just modifying the **method create** :

```
def create
      if @tournoi = Tournoi.new(payload: params['payload'])
          @tournoi.save
.......
```

Not parsing the **params** will save the payload but it will save another tournoi that has a **payload nil**

all i need to do is add a validation in my model to avoid a tournoi that has a **nil** payload to be saved :

```
class Tournoi < ApplicationRecord
  validates :payload, presence: true, allow_nil: false
```

Thats it gets the job done :)